# DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

Something happened today, its work fine at morning. I doesnt touch the code
and now its dont work,
show me this error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (13/09 03:46 PM) at position 0
(1): Unexpected character' in position:243 Stack trace:
#0 position(243): DateTime->__construct('13/09 03:46 PM', Object(DateTimeZone)) #1 {main} thrown
```

the code:

```
$together = $cc_name . '/' . $e_name;
$ts = new DateTime(date('d/m h:i A'), new DateTimeZone('Asia/Jerusalem'));
$ts->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($together));
```

`$together` its a variable that take `$cc_name` as mainland of timezone from sql, and `$e_name` its the city.

Whats wrong?

**EDIT**:
`var_dump` result of `$together` its `string(11) "Asia/Urumqi"`

Comment: Why are you attempting to create a date from a non-standard time format? Especially one you're not passing in, just creating as now? Per the docs, if you want the current time and want to pass in the timezone, [use "now"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateTime doesn't recognize the format. You'll need to specify the format

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m g:i A', '13/09 03:46 PM');
// 09/13/2023 3:46 PM since this is 2023 and no year was specified
echo $date->format('m/d/Y g:i A');
```

The problem with that is you're making the format complicated in the first place and having to do twice the work (all `date` is doing is outputting the current date/time). A better way to do this would be

```
$together = $cc_name . '/' . $e_name;
$ts = new DateTime(); // current time
$ts->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($together));
echo $ts->format('d/m h:i A');
```